# svn eclipse move project to another folder

Tags: svn

I have uploaded one of my projects in a folder but now I want to transfer it to the trunk folder. How can I do that? Or can I delete the project and create a new one?

Comment: What I did finally. Right click on my project -> Team -> Disconnect... I chose "Also delete the SVN meta information from the file system". And then I shared the file again putting it in the new folder. Its not an important issue but maybe it will help someone. Thank you.